# How to extract curve control points from Rhino NURB file

Tags: plugins

I want to implement a Rhino plugin to extract location properties of NURB curves Control Points.
if you draw a curve or a solid shape like Sphere. you have some points to draw and also you have some Control Points.

to know more about NURB ad Control Points you can read this [link](http://www.rhino3d.com/nurbs?PageSpeed=noscript)

Comment: What do you mean by a "Rhino plugin?" Are you referring to the Rhino JavaScript engine that runs on the Java virtual machine?

Comment: No, Rhino is a 3D Design Application, if you check the link you will see

Comment: OK. I've added an edit to remove the "rhino" tag as that tag means something else at Stack Overflow. (And I don't know anything about this Rhino, so I am sorry to say I can't help you.) You may want to try to find tags that are more specific; "plugins" will be unlikely to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VS 2012 You should install the new Rhino Components . then you can retrieve the NURBS Properties like this :

```
Surface sr = obj_ref.Surface();
if (null == sr)
    return Result.Failure;

NurbsSurface ns = sr.ToNurbsSurface();
if (null == ns)
    return Result.Failure;


foreach (var point in ns.Points)
{
    doc.Objects.AddPoint(point.Location);
}

foreach (var knot in ns.KnotsU)
{
  // do anything by KnotsU
}


foreach (var knot in ns.KnotsV)
{
    // do anything by KnotsV
}

doc.Views.Redraw();
```

Answer (score 1):

This Python code extracts the control points of selected curves and associates curves names to extracted control points.

```
import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs
from System.Drawing import Color
import Rhino as Rh
#Collecting the curves
obj = rs.GetObjects("Select curves",4)
#adding a Layer as a parent layer
rs.AddLayer("Knots")
for curve in obj:
    if rs.IsCurve(curve):
#Creating new layers from objects name
            LayerName = rs.ObjectName(curve)
            rs.AddLayer(LayerName,Color.Aqua,True,False,"Knots")
            points = rs.CurvePoints(curve)
            if points:
                for pt in points:
                    CtrlPoint = rs.AddPoint(pt)
                    rs.ObjectLayer(CtrlPoint,LayerName)
                    rs.ObjectName(CtrlPoint,rs.ObjectName(curve))
```